# Electron App automated testing WDIO Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-forge, node-sqlite3, wdio

I'm encountering an issue when running automated tests with WebdriverIO (WDIO) in my Electron application. The error I'm facing is:

`Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file`

However, when I run the application manually using `npm start` or create an executable file with `npm make` and run it, I don't encounter this error.

Here are some details about my setup:

- I'm using SQLite3 for the database.
- The application is an Electron app with TypeScript, Webpack, and React (i used ElectronForge).
- The error specifically occurs during WDIO test runs.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this WDIO testing error would be greatly appreciated.